# Spark memory leak

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory-leaks, pyspark

I'm on spark 2.1 and I've been running into a memory leak in spark, specifically when using pyspark's [subtract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) function. I'm running this in a loop where the data frame being subtracted from should eventually hit 0 but what I see is memory usage on the driver continues to increase until it dies.

```py
for row in counts_df.collect():
    customer_df = all_grouped_df.select('name').where(all_grouped_df.customer == row['customer'])

    pre_count = all_df.count()

    all_df = all_df.subtract(customer_df)

    post_count = all_df.count()

    diff_count = pre_count-post_count
    # do some other stuff
```

It seems to me `all_df = X` doesn't actually overwrite the previous object? Thats the only conclusion I can come to since the data in `all_df` decreases with each loop.

Is there any way around this or a different way to implement the `subtract` functionality?

Edit: I ran this with only the subtract function (no counts) and it didn't seem to leak anything. I think maybe the leak has something to do with how I'm running `count`?

Comment: When you do subtract without count, do you mean no count in loop or no count at all ..even outside loop?

Comment: No count at all.

Comment: Well if there is no count i.e. no action ...whatever you are doing inside doesn't really execute at all . try a count outside loop and see if you are getting results you want..

Comment: I need to count inside the loop, at least after the subtract to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've added a read to run example in a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146738/spark-memory-leak

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue when running on cluster mode with yarn. Strangely the issue disappears in client mode. My guess is that python memory is never released when using pyspark in yarn client mode.

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

1. It makes exactly a new data frame when you operate on the data frame. Specially not the action methods.
2. I'm also feeling troubled. Fine, I guess you were falling into 2 pitfalls dig by the damned spark developer. The data lineage would increase as you do "all_df = all_df.substract", every time a new df is created, the data relationship is enlongered, and the old ones are not deleted because you were referencing them.

So you are either stack overflow dues to very long data lineage or memory boom dues to too many data frames kept in memory.